# Jacoco: Aggregating branch coverage report of multiple test case method

Tags: junit, ant, jacoco

I am using Ant JUnit.

```
<for list="${test.classes.list}"  param="class" delimiter=",">
<sequential>
    <for list="${@{class}}"  param="method" delimiter=",">
        <sequential>
            <jacoco:coverage destfile="${basedir}/jacoco.exec">
            <junit fork="true">
                 ......
                <test name="@{class}" methods="@{method}"/>
            </junit>
            </jacoco:coverage>
            <jacoco:report>     
                ......
                <csv destfile="coverage/@{class}.@{method}/report.csv"/>
            </jacoco:report>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</sequential>
```

In the property file, I have:

```
test.classes.list=a.b.C,d.e.F
a.b.C=test1,test2
d.e.F=test1,test2,test3
```

Jacoco will produce a report for each test case method.

The problem is branch coverage for each class is not accurate as covered branches may be overlapped.

How do I aggregate the reports to get a correct branch coverage for whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JaCoCo comes with [Ant tasks](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) to launch Java programs with execution recording and for creating coverage reports from the recorded data. Execution data can be collected and managed with the tasks coverage, agent, dump and [merge](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html#merge).

This is an example from their Web page of how to merge a set of `*.exec` files:

```
<jacoco:merge destfile="merged.exec">
    <fileset dir="executionData" includes="*.exec"/>
</jacoco:merge>
```